# Rails find object id on has_many association

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm trying to get the transaction id associated with the current_user but rails shos this error below

error:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Transaction with id=92
>   [WHERE "transactions"."user_id" = 24])

iv'e tried use where and just the transaction and with a conditional comparing the transaction.user_id with the current_user.id but show error!

someone have any hint about this kind of issue?

```
model user

user has_many transactions

model transaction 

transaction belongs to user


transaction controller

def new
@transaction = Transaction.new
end

def create

@transaction = Transaction.build_user

end



def show

@transaction = current_user.transactions.find(params[:id])

end
```

Comment: Did you copy paste this? If so: You do recognise that you have a type error in your transaction model? It is not "trasaction" belongs to user but "transaction". An "n" is missing there.

Comment: In your `Transaction` with id `92` there is no `user_id`. Check that using your console typing `rails c`. Then find the `Transaction` with id '92', to see if it contains the `user_id`

Comment: Emu, contains. and thank you

Comment: `@transaction = Transaction.build_user` just _initializes_ an user associated to the transaction, but does not save the user to the database - user `create_user` instead. Furthermore that will create a new user that is not the `current_user`, is that what you want?

Comment: Maybe Its transaction doesn't belong to this user.

Answer (score 0):

As many pointed in comments `build_user` does indeed create a new User instance (without saving it). Furthermore I believe `build_user` is not a class method but an instance method instead. Therefore Transaction.build_user should be raising 'undefined method' exception. Also, build_user returns a User instance, so even if you're code was `@transaction = Transaction.new.build_user` @transaction would be a newly created User instance.

And again, what others already pointed out in comments, your transaction wouldn't necessarily be associated to the `current_user` for you to fetch it like this in subsequent calls during the same session, rather, and supposing you properly built and saved the user, you would need to login as this 'new user' in order to.